# How to set status bar color same as to Navigation bar color in iOs 7 using Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, ios6, xcode4.2, statusbar

Now i Am using Xcode 4.2 to develop app.and the app is running on iOS 7 iPhone.My problem related with status bar color.I want the status bar color is same color as of navigation bar color.I am using this code for setting navigation bar image ,here is my code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

How we can set the status bar color?now is light gray color>>Many thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS6 you can't change the image or the color of the status bar apart from this 2 styles:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

Comment: If you are using XCode 4.2 you are not compiling with iOS7, another thing is that you are running your app in a iOS7 device, but it's compiled with iOS6

Comment: so there is no way to change the color of status bar ...?

Comment: No apart from those 2 styles, sorry

Answer (score 0):

chakra's suggestion to add the line of code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

works.  Add it to your [viewdidload](/questions/tagged/viewdidload)function in the swift files of your controllers.  This allows the status bar to be the same color as the navigation bar.  I added this as an answer instead of a comment, because I cannot add comments to other answers as yet.  The line of code above this line of code does not work for me though.

Answer (score -2):

This works:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor  = UIColor.untSimeioblue
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: Explain your answer, this makes no sense.